# What vintage movie had this blue floating holographic head talking to some kind of military installation?

Tags: story-identification, movie

In the comedic music video [SPACE FORCE - The Theme Song](https://youtu.be/_AUXpnB065o) there are many clips of vintage scifi films, some of which I recognize.

This one however, of a large blue floating holographic head talking to some kind of military installation does not look at all familiar.

Does anyone recognize this film?

[image: Video screenshot, blue floating holographic head]

Comment: Gee, freaking thanks.  I was teenaged when that film came out.  Now here you are calling it "vintage" like its old or something.

Comment: @JRE I'm trying to make excuses for not recognizing it, or maybe I'm referring to the dated nature of the plot, or the special effects technology, or maybe I'm... Anyway, now I want to see it!

Comment: “What do we do?” (Space monocle deploys) “We die.” It’s a very 80s movie but it’s also one I remember fondly. Worth a watch if at least to get any references to it.

Comment: Is it bad that I recognized pretty much every clip from that video instantly?  Including several from The Last Starfighter... :-)

Comment: @BrianMinton I was trying to figure out how to ask that question, but then thought it might be closed as a list-question. However, if someone were to ask then answer, or ask then start a community-wiki answer, or just post an additional answer here... there are several there that I am sure many people would be interested in knowing about. *Oh, and no, that's not bad!* ;-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### [*The Last Starfighter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/) (1984)

> Video game expert Alex Rogan finds himself transported to another planet after conquering The Last Starfighter video game only to find out it was just a test. He was recruited to join the team of best starfighters to defend their world from the attack.

The character in question is [Xur](http://thelaststarfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Xur).

[image: Xur]

---

I found this by doing a reverse image search on the screenshot you posted in the question.

Comment: @uhoh This is absolutely from The Last Starfighter, I recognized it immediately and would have put it as an answer if this weren’t already here. This is the scene when the Big Bad reveals his evil plans and destroys the Starfighter Force.

Comment: @uhoh You asked what the film was, you got your answer. It doesn't matter how you get the answer. I only added it because it is useful to people to know how the answer came about whether it is knowledge of it, google search terms, a related question or searching the image.

Comment: Thanks! Having been informed that your answer is "objectively perfect" I've accepted without delay; anything else would be illogical ;-)

Comment: It’s not to defend their world from attack. It’s to defend the frontier against Xur and the Ko-Dan Armada!

Comment: Interesting. That plot sounds a bit like a Batman Beyond episode where 3 children got the highest score at a game (called "Sentries of the Last Cosmos") and were recruited as (fake) sentries because of it. That episode probably got inspired by the movie.

Comment: @Clockwork Gave me a nice nostalgia trip and that's almost certainly inspired by the movie :P In fact the [DCAU Wiki](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Sentries_of_the_Last_Cosmos) specifically cites it as such in the trivia section, though it doesn't give any references for that.

Comment: I feel offended that you reverse image searched and didn't remember watching this movie!