# Movie with Zoltar in a trailer park named Paradise and a boy playing a video game then being recruited by aliens to fight in space

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie starts out in a trailer park named Paradise. A boy plays a video game and then is recruited to help fight in space for Aliens.

Comment: If you remember more details please add such as year when you watch it, Language any recognizable actor. That will help others to answer.

Comment: wasn't the trailer park called "Starlight Star Bright"?

Comment: @Jim  Yes, although I'm not sure it wasn't "Starlite Star Brite" or some other variant spelling of either word, often used in business names.

Comment: By "Zoltar", do you mean a video transmission of a sneering villain, in the manner of Zoltar from *Battle of the Planets*?  [Xur](https://supercultshow.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/the-last-starfighter/laststarfighter4/) fits that description in *The Last Starfighter*.

Comment: Note to editors: ___DO NOT___ remove information from the question, you have no idea if it is a conflated memory, erroneous information or is actually correct. Just because you think you know the answer here doesn't mean you do. There might be a The Last Starfighter/Big mix film with elements from either. On top of that incorrect information can help others who also remember the incorrect elements to find their answer.

Comment: Hello Marilyn, do you think you can remember some more details? For instance, when did you see it? Where? In what language? Please see [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561), perhaps something will jog your memory.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194746/what-vintage-movie-had-this-blue-floating-holographic-head-talking-to-some-kind

Answer (score 93):

#### [*The Last Starfighter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/) (1984)

> Video game expert Alex Rogan finds himself transported to another planet after conquering The Last Starfighter video game only to find out it was just a test. He was recruited to join the team of best starfighters to defend their world from the attack.

Comment: Damn, the first time I ever recognized a film from the title alone, and the question is already answered - kudos

Comment: Man I love this movie!

Comment: Didn't we *all* dream something like this for virtually *every* computer game we played? ;-)

Comment: I'd love a modern remake of this, but I don't know how anyone could redo Robert Preston's Centarui, and it would almost be an act of vandalism to try. So they'll just have to make Earnest Cline's Armada instead. (Universal is working on a script)

Comment: Modern remake: Jack Black plays Centauri, don't know about Alex Logan. Maybe one of the actors from Stranger Things: Finn Wolfhard or Gaten Matarazzo?

Answer (score 28):

[HorusKol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/373/horuskol)’s [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215013/83278) is correct. However, *[The Last Starfighter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087597/)* had no character named Zoltar. Similar sounding names that were in the film may be [Xur](https://thelaststarfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Xur) played by Norman Snow or the bounty hunting [Zando-Zan](https://thelaststarfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Zando-Zan).

Zoltar was the name of a coin-operated fortune telling machine in *[Big](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J62jciQ1PbY)* (1988). Tom Hanks played the lead role of Josh Baskin, aged 12 or 13 at the beginning of the story. Josh is humiliated at a carnival in front of a cute girl from school for not being tall enough to safely ride one of the rides. He sulks away to find a Zoltar machine and wishes to be big. The next morning, Josh wakes up in the body of a thirty-year-old man. For a few weeks, he enjoys the “easy” life of an adult, has a few awkward experiences that his youthful naïveté blind him to but that are humorous to the audience, and variously impresses or incites jealousy in his workmates with his refreshing outlook.

[image: Josh wishes to be big]

In the end, Josh gets homesick and decides he had it better as a kid.

[image: “Big” Josh wishing to be a kid again]

Watch the entire trailer below.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with aliens and is barely relevant.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi It sure is about Zoltar, though.

Comment: good answer because OP has conflated a couple of features from two movies, so this answer is addressing one of those items @DJSpicyDeluxe-Levi

Comment: I think it's nice info, but since the question has had the Zoltar part removed, it no longer has pretty much any relevance.  Now, it's just a comment on the other answer being right, and a lot of info on an unrelated movie.  It think it's fine information... but really doesn't constitute an answer so much as a commentary on an initial mistake the OP made.

Comment: @K-H-W The title was edited by a third party to remove information and that ___should not___ have happened. I have edited Zoltar back in for this reason, we shouldn't assume things on the OP's behalf. For all we know there is a movie out there that is a combination of both of these and so isn't actually either. This answer is fine as it is.

Comment: It could have been a little known fan edit, the biggest starfighter

Comment: [Battle of the Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Planets) would have been a better guess.  Not only is there a 'Zoltar', it also involves aliens.

Comment: The incorrectly remembered name is presumably why the OP wasn't able to find the correct film for themselves.