# Floating transparent sphere beaming something into a crater? (Space Force! theme song video)

Tags: story-identification, movie, art

The video [Space Force - The Theme Song // Songify This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AUXpnB065o) is a rich source of old SciFi movie images.

- [What vintage movie had this blue floating holographic head talking to some kind of military installation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194746/51174)

At about `02:00` can be seen a large nearly-transparent sphere hovering over a large crater seen from the side, in a desert that *might be* on Earth. From the bottom of the sphere emanates a translucent red "beam" that disappears into the center of the crater.

There is a shimmering disk-like ring around the sphere's equator (Saturnesque).

**Question:** From what work of Science Fiction film or art does this short clip come from? What is it doing, and is an artist identification possible?

(the tiny red sports car on the left is "contraband" from the video that uses this clip)

[image: screenshot from Space Force - The Theme Song // Songify This]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is from the Starman (1984) movie staring Jeff Bridges as the Starman.

Here is a short YouTube Clip showing the Mirrored globe (his rescue spaceship) above the crater, picking up the Starman.

[Starts with that exact image](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPPMHA65HIg)

Comment: @uhoh Dont forget to accept the answer if its correct.

Comment: I did finally, sorry for the delay! Also, I didn't receive a notification of your comment  - I would have if you added this under the question, but here I need to comment first before the `@` works.